# How can I import posts into different wordpress multisites at once?

Tags: multisite

I have a CSV of posts with the title in one column and the post body in another column, then another column with the subdomain it goes to. I'm trying to import  these [specific] posts into the multiple sub sites of a wordpress multisite installation that they belong without having to log into each sub site. Does anyone know of a method to go about doing this?

Comment: There are several options, but you may need to modify a bit for your use case. Check here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Importing_Content and I'll comment with another link to an answer with some other info to look at if you're building something.

Comment: Actually I take it back, the link I was thinking of doesn't offer much beyond the codex link to import tools. I'd start there.